# Array of struct Error

Tags: c, arrays, struct, compiler-errors

Here is my code:

```
typedef struct Node *link;
typedef struct Node
{           
    char data;
    int count;    
    link right;
    link left;
    link next; 
}nd;
node nd[100];
link current;
```

When I tried to do this in the main

```
current = current->nd[0].right;
```

It showed me:
  [Error] 'struct Node' has no member named 'nd'
How I can fix it?

Comment: Your `current` is of type `link`. `link` is a struct which does not have a member named `nd`. Seems pretty clear to me. Your `nd` is an array of `node` completely separate from `current`. What relationship do you want between them? It's not expressed in your code.

Comment: sorry typo, edited

Comment: @joejordishon Your edition is wrong and does not make sense

Comment: That edit doesn't help. You have now just created a type called `nd` (which is of type `struct Node`). `current` is still of type `link`, and that structure still does not have a member called `nd`.

Comment: C is a case-sensitive language. As such, `node` in your code is undefined.

Comment: Not directly related, but you should avoid hiding pointer types behind typedefs such as `typedef struct Node *link;`. This only adds confusion.

Comment: @machine_1 I thought so too, but this defines both `Node` and `node`. Convention would have it be `node_t` and `node` to avoid rampant confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
current = current->nd[0].right;
```

To this:

```
current = nd[0].right;
```

Or, if you've already assigned something to current, then do this:

```
current = current->right;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean the following.

```
typedef struct Node *link;
typedef struct Node
{           
    char data;
    int count;    
    link right;
    link left;
    link next; 
}node;


node nd[100];
link current;

//...

current = nd;
current = current[0].right;
```